# chocolat.js + swiper - images open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am using chocolat.js with swiper.

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper chocolat-parent">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="..." class="chocolat-image">
        <img src="..." alt="swiper image">
      </a>
    </div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="..." class="chocolat-image">
        <img src="..." alt="swiper image">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something like this. The issue is some images open in a new tab instead of chocolat popup. I was testing that behaviour for some time and I realised the problem is "loop: true" property in swiper object. Duplicated slides (swiper's loop works like this - duplicate slides) seems to not work properly and just open in a new tab. I tried to reinitiate chocolat after event "changeSlide" but it didn't help. Any ideas?

JS:

```
$('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat().data('chocolat');
```

```
new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    speed: 450,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
    },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-right',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-left',
    },
  });
```

Simple initiation. nothing more

Comment: can you add  javascript  which you used in your problem?

Comment: Just added - look at post

Comment: so you implement Swiper slider with  Chocolat am I right?